# Julia Differential Equations: Kuramoto model as DDE: Results don't converge when constant_lags are specified

Tags: julia, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

Copy-pasting from the issue I opened on github (https://github.com/SciML/DifferentialEquations.jl/issues/983).

Hello,

Here is my problem: I am trying to simulate the Kuramoto model with time delays but delays come from a matrix D where ij-th element describes the time delay between oscillator i and oscillator j. Moreover, oscillators are connected with a weighted connectivity matrix C. The model is written as

d(theta_i) / dt = omega_i + K * sum_over_j( C[i, j] * sin( theta_j(t - D[i, j] - theta_i(t)) )

Where omega_i is the natural frequency and thetas are phases of oscillators

Here is how I coded the function:

```
function kuramoto_dde!(dtheta, theta, h, p, t)
    omega, C, K, D = p

    for i in eachindex(omega)
        sum_coup = 0.
        # Do the sigma term (second term in the model)
        for j in eachindex(omega)
            if D[i, j] != 0 # Some of the connectivities are missing so delay applies only for available ones
                thetaj = h(p, t - D[i, j])[j]
            else
                thetaj = theta[j]
            end
            sum_coup += C[i, j] * sin(thetaj - theta[i])
        end
        # Write the full equation
        dtheta[i] = omega[i] + K * sum_coup
    end
    nothing
end
```

The code to run the simulations:

```
using MAT, DifferentialEquations, LinearAlgebra
# These MATLAB files contain matrices C and D
C = matread(raw"C:\Users\duodenum\Desktop\brain_stuff\pr_basics\data\chaudhuri_sc.mat")["J"]
D = matread(raw"C:\Users\duodenum\Desktop\brain_stuff\pr_basics\data\chaudhuri_D.mat")["D"]

n = size(C)[1]
dt = 0.002
tspan = (0., 300.)
timevector = 0:dt:tspan[2]

# Define the history function
h(p, t) = rand(n) * 2. * pi

# Omegas come from a gaussian distribution with mean omega_0 and variance dispersion
omega_0 = 10.
dispersion = 9.
omega = 2. * pi .* (omega_0 .+ sqrt(dispersion) .* (randn((n, 1))))

# Randomly distributed initial conditions
theta_0 = 2. * pi * rand(n)

K = 1000
p = (omega, C, K, D)

prob = DDEProblem(kuramoto_dde!, theta_0, h, tspan, p; constant_lags = D)

alg = MethodOfSteps(Rosenbrock23())
sol = solve(prob, alg; saveat = timevector)
println("SOLUTION COMPLETE")
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Warning: dt(0.0) <= dtmin(2.220446049250313e-16) at t=0.0, and step error estimate = 1.0. Aborting. There is either an error in your model specification or the true solution is unstable.
└ @ SciMLBase C:\Users\duodenum\.julia\packages\SciMLBase\GmToj\src\integrator_interface.jl:599
```

On the other hand, if I don't specify constant lags:

```
prob = DDEProblem(kuramoto_dde!, theta_0, h, tspan, p)

alg = MethodOfSteps(Rosenbrock23())
sol = solve(prob, alg; saveat = timevector)
println("SOLUTION COMPLETE")
```

I get the solution but it is very slow. I tried using `constant_lags = D[:]` or `constant_lags = D[:]'` as well but none of them worked. Is there a way to specify constant_lags in this situation without messing up the results?

Thanks for the great work with this package (and the sciML ecosystem in general!)
Yasir

Comment: Does `h(p, t) = rand(n) * 2. * pi` actually do what you expect it to do? Is the RNG only called at the creation  of this function or is it called at every invocation of the history function (for negative `t`)? Try creating the vector of angles first and then using the constant, static angles in the history function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ill-posed. `h(p, t) = rand(n) * 2. * pi` gives a different random number each time, since it's just a function calling `randn`. The history is is almost surely not continuous or differentiable and isn't even well-defined (it does not evaluate to the same value each time). The DDE solution is not defined in any sensible mathematical way. The adaptivity is probably trying really hard to figure out why it cannot get a single unique solution and gives up because there is no solution to the model as posed.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. As far as I understood from the documentation, when we are defining history, we put the values that are before time point 0. So I changed the history definition to following:


`history = rand(n) * 2. * pi`
`h(p, t) = history`
But unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Perhaps your `C` and `D` are specified in a way that leads to the error? Taking your code and making that one history change per Chris' suggestion I can't get that error at all with randomly assigned `C` and `D` matrices (tested on N=5, 20). Another minor note: `h(p, t-tau)` should return `theta[j]` when `tau=0`, so I don't think that if statement is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for various tips. Chris's answer makes perfect sense. Posting this just in case somebody else has a similar problem: In my case, the delay matrix D had 0s in the diagonal and it turns out the lags vector doesn't like 0s inside it. So the following modification solved the error:

```
lags = D_over_v[:]
deleteat!(lags, lags .== 0)
prob = DDEProblem(kuramoto_dde!, theta_0, h, tspan, p; constant_lags = lags)
```

Comment: Delays of 0 are somewhat nefarious. Delays which are non-constant and hit zero are very difficult to handle, and so the solver thinks this is the most difficult case ever. Of course, with a constant lag being zero... that's just no lag so it should be fine haha. We can make this case error so that the user can filter those out (or see that they had some delays of zero that weren't expected)

Comment: I think this would be great from a UI perspective. End-users like me who don't see what's going on inside the black boxes of those integrators might think that it is fine and reasonable to have 0s on the diagonal of a delay matrix if they are working with stuff like coupled oscillators or biophysical models of the brain. Thanks for the insight!